# Best way to pg_dump PostgreSQL on RDS to S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws

I need to dump my PostgreSQL on RDS to a file on S3 periodically (to use it elsewhere than AWS).

Is there a better way than running a script that runs `pg_dump` and uploads results to S3 using e.g. `boto3`?

Comment: Nope, that's a fine way of handling this use case.

Comment: you can use `--format=directory --jobs=...` for fastening process

Answer (score 22):

You can directly upload the (gzipped) `pg_dump` results to s3 using the aws cli:

```
pg_dump -Z 9 -v -h ${DATABASE_HOST} -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME} | aws s3 cp --storage-class STANDARD_IA --sse aws:kms - s3://my-bucket/dump.sql.gz
```

At work we wrapped this in a script which additionally fetches the required credentials from parameter store and then stores the backup in s3. The script runs within a docker container as a scheduled ecs task. Maybe [the code in this repository](https://github.com/Birne94/rds-s3-database-backup) will help you.

Comment: But this doesn't stream right? So if the database is really large, like 100GB+ I suppose you want streaming. Consider https://github.com/jameshy/pgdump-aws-lambda

Comment: It streams STDOUT from "pg_dump" to STDIN of "aws s3 cp -" (that's what the "-" means). To restore, use "aws s3 cp s3://... - | gunzip | psql"